# Sitecore 9.3 Federated authentication - idp claim is missing Parameter name: identity

Tags: federated-authentication

I am working on adding SAML federated authentication to my sitecore site. I am follwing the instructions given here

I can see the claims being returned. But when creating the external user, I am getting this error `idp claim is missing Parameter name: identity`.

I have added the following claim transformation as mentioned in couple of answers for similar question. But this has not fixed my issue.

`<transformation name="Idp Claim" ref="federatedAuthentication/sharedTransformations/transformation[@name='set idp claim']" />`

The shared transformation is already there in Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config

```
<sharedTransformations hint="list:AddSharedClaimsTransformation">
    <transformation name="set idp claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SetIdpClaimTransform, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" />
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to sitecore stack exchange. Can you edit the text and fix the instructions link or add them to the question?

Comment: In your custom Owin.config file have you added <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation"><transformation name="Idp Claim" ref="federatedAuthentication/sharedTransformations/setIdpClaim" />?

Comment: Hi I am also getting the same error. Any luck with this? Please tell how you were able to resolve this issue?